# Approval Workflow starting when columns are changed

Tags: workflow, calendar, approval-process

Have a calendar approval workflow that has been working great up until today, I added a few new columns to the calendar new item form and it kicked off workflows on every approval I've had on the calendar in the past several months.  I'm assuming it's because I have the workflow option of "Start workflow automatically when item is changed" selected.

So I guess my question is how do I prevent it from starting workflows on all my existing items when a change to a column is made but if an item is modified it will still kick off the workflow?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like I need to add some kind of an exception so that it won't kick the workflow off when there's a global change done to the list.  Suggestions on how I would do this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to uncheck workflow start when the item is updated or you need to specific condition for approval Workflow on item changed.